# Flutter: Google Play services out of date

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 8660): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 13400000 but found 13280022

I'm trying to run example app from google_maps_plugin repo on Nexus S and Pixel Phone emulators which both run on Android Pie.

There are questions, not on the flutter side specifically. I've failed to apply their solutions.

**What I've done so far**

1) I don't have this option in my emulator
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45312782/9779791

2) this one is on the flutter tag but solution was a dependency fix
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53982212/9779791

3) Not clear to me how to downgrade google play services in gradle [Google Play services out of date. Requires 10298000 but found 10084470](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610703/google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-10298000-but-found-10084470)

4) tried to download play services from this link with emulator, but since I don't have playstore app, I can't associate my account with it,
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms

> This Google account is not yet associated with a device. Please access the Play Store app on your device before installing apps.

Comment: Did you try to run your app on older API? Or to test your app on older device? I'm still getting this message when running on AVD image with target set to Android 7.0 (API 24).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To run applications that require Play Services, you need to have an emulator with Google Play on board.

When creating a new emulator (`Tools -> AVD Manager -> Create new virtual device...` in Android Studio), there are only a few that support Google Play. The AVD Manager indicates which devices qualify for Android versions with ***Play Store*** preinstalled (highlighted in yellow):

[image]

After selecting a device that supports the Play Store, the system images will target a *Google Play* version:

[image]

Now, your emulator will provide all required features.

Comment: Since I had other play apps, I didn't notice that I was missing Google Play, it solved my issue. Thanks. But why is the error message is related to version, rather than absence of Play Services?

Comment: This didn't solve problem for me. If you want to test on older device which has Android 7.0 for example it will show this message.

Answer (score 7):

You need to update the google play services on the emulator. 
Firstly, make sure that your emulator is using a google play image then;

1. Click the ... icon at the side of the emulator
2. Goto Play Services -> Update
3. You may need to sign-into the google play using valid google credentials
4. Click on the update button in the google play to update the google services apk(s)

[image]

Comment: What if you actually intentionally do want to test on older device? I'm making an app in Flutter and Firebase Auth is not working, showing the message `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(18963): Google Play services out of date`.

Comment: @mjakic No matter how old the device is, if it has Google Play Services, it should also have the Play Store and update the Play Services.

Comment: I updated versions in gradle file from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup and now it works...there isn't this warning anymore